# .+$ fails to match remainder of line

Tags: regular-expressions, query-replace-regexp

This matches nothing:

```
    Query replace regexp (default \.org.+  → ): \.org.+$  →
```

The same without '$' matches incompletely:

[image]

I'd like to be able to match `\.org` and all that follows.

Comment: Can't reproduce, either using re-search or re-builder. Please update posting the queries and the text alone as code, as well as other relevant data, as it cloud be file encoding, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\.org.+$` works for me, starting from `emacs -Q`.

Try starting Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file). Do you see the same thing? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

(Maybe pay attention too to what whitespace you're trying to match. Your question is underspecified.  All we have to go on is your screenshot - we have no idea what whitespace chars you're trying to match, etc.)

Comment: Yes, it works starting from `emacs -Q`.

Comment: You can use command `comment-region` to bisect your init file, commenting-out 1/2, then 3/4, 7/8, 15/16, etc of the file. (With `C-u`, `comment-region` UNcomments the region.)

Comment: I think `weathergrass` is causing the problem.